# MySQL table transformation with counts

Tags: mysql, count, row, summary

I have a large query that I will simplify below to make it easier to understand. I'm not sure how best toi classify what I need to do other than say I need to analyse my data and produce some counts.

In this example I have a table of information regarding books

```
Author, Title, Category
```

Where category can be one of History, Fiction, Sport or Travel

What I require as an output is

```
Author, count(History), count(Fiction), count(Sport), count(Travel)
```

for each author.

Example output:

```
Author        History   Fiction   Sport   Travel
J.Patterson      0         21       1       3
R.Ludlum         3         43       3       0
```

Will probable need to add a total column at the end.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Author,
    SUM(Category='History') AS 'History',
    SUM(Category='Fiction') AS 'Fiction',
    SUM(Category='Sport') AS 'Sport',
    SUM(Category='Travel') AS 'Travel'
FROM books
GROUP BY Author
```

Comment: Just what I needed, couldn't see the wood between the trees.

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, it would work correctly if you removed `Category` from the `group by` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not having an expandable and nicer output such as `Author | CategoryName | Count` ?

```
SELECT Author, Category, COUNT(*) FROM books GROUP BY Author, Category;
```